# (Proxy) How can I direct one computer's traffic via another computer?

Tags: networking, proxy, tor

How can I direct one computer's traffic via another computer?

For example: 
Let's say computer A's external IP is 1.1.1.1
and I want that its entire traffic will go through computer B whose IP is 2.2.2.2.

(Eventually, the websites will think that Computer A's IP is 2.2.2.2)

I don't want you to tell me how to code it, just help me understand what should I learn in order to program it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide your ip you can use a reverse shell over ssh tunnel. I don't know how tor works.